# Compare Two Arrays and Remove Duplicates Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have two arrays and I would like to create a new array that compares the two and removes both instances of duplicates.

I have a custom object:

```
struct SubService: Identifiable, Hashable, Encodable {
   var id: String = UUID().uuidString
   var name: String
   var charge: String
   var price: Double
}
```

My two arrays:

```
let array1: [SubService] = [SubService(name: "Men's Haircut", charge: "service", price: 10), SubService(name: "Fade", charge: "service", price: 10)]

let array2: [SubService] = [SubService(name: "Fade", charge: "service", price: 10)]
```

Here is the result I'm looking for:

```
let result: [SubService] = [SubService(name: "Men's Haircut", charge: "service", price: 10)]
```

I have tried the following but it returns the same array as `array1`. I'm assuming because of the `id`?

```
let filteredArray = Array(Set(array1).subtracting(array2))
```

print statements:

`ARRAY 1: [SubService(id: "F9EDBBC0-3786-4718-B6BE-C31F26D6E0F0", name: "Fade", charge: "service", price: 10.0), SubService(id: "D91939DD-C339-4A56-B09D-C19ABA56A48B", name: "Men\'s Haircut", charge: "service", price: 10.0)]`

`ARRAY 2: [SubService(id: "373CE5F9-ECB0-4572-BD27-8BC71F96163B", name: "Fade", charge: "service", price: 10.0)]`

`FILTERED ARRAY: [SubService(id: "D91939DD-C339-4A56-B09D-C19ABA56A48B", name: "Men\'s Haircut", charge: "service", price: 10.0), SubService(id: "F9EDBBC0-3786-4718-B6BE-C31F26D6E0F0", name: "Fade", charge: "service", price: 10.0)]`

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Define "duplicate".

Comment: @Larme Duplicate = Exactly like something else. In this case, they are duplicates of each other

Comment: You asked this question earlier today, didn’t the duplicate question help you?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes that's right. The "solution" I've provided above is what the duplicate question provided me with. However it returns an empty array

Comment: Where does the `$0` come from? The `id` of the entry of `array2` differs from the `id` of the second entry of `array1`, because each `UUID()` creates a new unique identifier. If you leave out `$0.` your `filteredArray` should end up similar to `array1`, possibly in a different order.  If you get an empty array, your `$0` should be to blame.

Comment: I'm asking to pinpoint your initial guess. You mean by duplicate: Same Name, same charge & same price? But same UUID too? What's the UUID of each `SubService` in `array1` & `array2` Could you either use `CustomStringConvertible` or a specific print method to print each values of `SubService`, and print them for `array1` & `array2`?

Comment: @pommy sorry that was a mistake. I have fixed it.

Comment: @Larme same name, charge, and price. UUID should not matter. In fact, even just name would be enough

Comment: That’s because you are comparing objects that aren’t equal

Comment: Implement Equatable and only include properties in the comparison that are relevant for equality. Or use a solution with a custom comparator

Comment: The `UUID` matters for `Hashable`. If you don't want it to matter, overload `func hash(into: inout Hasher)` to create a hash that ignores it.

Comment: @Larme I have added the print statements. I know I said it prints an empty array but I meant to say that it prints the same array.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what do you mean?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable

Comment: Or something like `array1.filter { e1 in !array2.contains(where: { $0.name == e1.name }) }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `Equatable` won't help, `Set` is based on `Hashable`.

Comment: @pommy true, I was thinking about a solution using the arrays rather than converting to Set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SubService has to conform to protocol Equatable

```
struct SubService: Identifiable, Hashable, Encodable, Equatable  {
   var id: String = UUID().uuidString
   var name: String
   var charge: String
   var price: Double
   static func ==(lhs: SubService, rhs: SubService) -> Bool {
      return lhs.name == rhs.name
   }
}


let arrSet = Set(array2)

let filteredArray = array1.filter{ !arrSet.contains($0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Reuse your items instead of creating new ones for each array declaration.

```
let mens = SubService(name: "Men's Haircut", charge: "service", price: 10)
let womens = SubService(name: "Woman's Haircut", charge: "service", price: 10)
let array1 = [mens, womens]
let array2 = [womens]
```

When you redefine the second item of `array1` in `let array2 = ...`, you create a new `UUID` that makes it different. You can actually see that in your printed values.